# How to change text in lowercase but keep Capital letter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to change my text in lowerCase but keep the first letter of each sentense uppercase.

### Input

> LOREM Ipsum is simply DUMMY text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem IPSUM. Has been the industry's standard dummy text
>   ever since the 1500s, WHEN an unknown printer took a galley.

### Expected

> Lorem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem ipsum. Has been the industry's standard dummy text
>   ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley.

I am new to regexp, I tried this :

```
expected = input.replace(/([A-Z])+/g, "\$&".toLowerCase())
```

Comment: You want to change only the 2nd ipsum to lower case ?

Comment: Why does `LOREM Ipsum` convert to `Lorem Ipsum` (note the capital `I`)?

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks, this is an error. I edited my post.

Comment: @mark maille, "I believe" I asked the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it in plain javascript by passing all in lowercase and add capitals letter by splitting your string.

```
input.toLowerCase().split('.').filter(x=> x.length > 0).map(x=> x[0].toUpperCase() ).join('.')
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it like this**

What i have done is first changed complete string to lowercase. now by using the regex i am searching for either the first word of the string. or any character which is preceded by `.` and any number of space characters and converting match to uppercase.

> Regex

```
^([a-z])|\.\s*([a-z])
```

- `^([a-z])` - Matches first word of string.
- `|` - Alternation same as logical OR.
- `\.\s*([a-z])` - Matches any `.` followed by any number of space character followed by alphabet.

```js
let str = "LOREM Ipsum is simply DUMMY text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem IPSUM. Has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, WHEN an unknown printer took a galley."

let op = str.toLowerCase().replace(/^([a-z])|\.\s*([a-z])/g, (match)=>match.toUpperCase())
console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a looped solution not a lot of regex

```
var str = input.split(" "); 
var expected = "";
str.map(function(c){
  expected += c.toLowerCase().replace(/^[a-z]/, c[0].toUpperCase())+ " "
})
expected = expected.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to stress out with regex as we can simply achieve this using a style attribute.

```
document.getElementById("inputId").style.textTransform = "initial";
```

For this, you need to find the id that is bind to that variable in HTML. That is all needed.

Comment: While this (probably) works, nowhere does OP mention that they're working with a DOM where you can set the style to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each sentence and try javascript like
`_str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + _str.substr(1).toLowerCase()` 
where `_str` is a sentence. This will be helpful when you don't have too many sentences to work on.

Answer (score 0):

```js
yourString
  .toLowerCase()
  .split(" ")
  .map(word => {
    word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1, yourString.length
   // you can get rid of the curly brackets they are there to just make it readable
  }))
  .join(" ")
```

- Turn the string to lower case
- split words and get an array of words
- use map to turn first character to uppercase and join it with the rest of the word with + operator (substring is there to get rid of the first letter)
- join all the words by using .join()